# Using Maildir as default mailspool

Tags: unix, maildir, mbox

Is it possible to use a Maildir as the mailspool for users on a *nix box?  I can get procmail to deliver to a Maildir without any problem, but I want to keep all the nifty features like finger knowing when mail last came in and shells alerting users when they have new mail...

**UPDATE:**
So, investigation shows that there is no "default mailspool" on a general level.  Finger (the client, not the server) has a hard-coded path.  pam_mail is what does the new mail notifications and has its own config, etc... so there is no "one place" to change this.

Comment: Somebody still uses finger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, since both finger and the shell rely on the access time of the mailbox in /var/mail (in mbox format) to display such information.  However, you could write a daemon that could "biff" logged-in users and modify ~/.plan appropriately to contain such information.

Answer (score 1):

`finger`, at least on FC14, is hard-coded to check /var/mail/*username*. For the shell there is the PAM module `pam_mail` that understands maildir.

Comment: So, pam_mail displays the "you have mail" message when I log in... who writes the "you have new mail" message to my terminal when I'm already logged in?

Comment: Oh, it seems that is built right into bash.  Ick